# Why running "dbt run" two times gives error

Tags: dbt

I have created the table model in dbt.
When I run dbt with dbt run the first time all is created.
Then I do dbt run one more time and get an error

```
Compilation Error in model database.schema.model_name
 When searching for a relation, dbt found an approximate match. Instead of guessing 
  which relation to use, dbt will move on. Please delete database.schema.model_name, or rename it to be less ambiguous.
```

Should not dbt drop and create a table model every time we run it?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, the model file name does matter...
I had simpleTest.sql ....
Needs to be simple_test.sql